# Why does Jesus say to tell everyone in Mark 5:19 but tell no one in Mark 5:43?

Tags: mark

> But Jesus said, “No, go home to your family, and tell them everything the Lord has done for you and how merciful he has been.”
>   Mark 5:19 NLT

Why is it that Jesus commanded the demon possessed man in verse 19 to tell to everyone that Jesus delivered him?

And in verse 43 He strictly commanded them not to. Why is that?

> Jesus gave them strict orders not to tell anyone what had happened, and then he told them to give her something to eat.
>   Mark 5:43 NLT

Answer (score 1):

> Mark 5:1 They went across the lake to the region of the Gerasenes.

> 11 A large herd of pigs was feeding on the nearby hillside.

Gerasenes was a gentile region where people raised pigs. They were not the over-zealous Jews who wanted to make him an earthly king. In fact, they wanted Jesus to leave them alone.

> Mark 5:17 And they began to implore Him to leave their region.

In this case, Jesus wanted the gentile people to know the good news of His power to deliver.

After this, he traveled to a crowded Jewish region.

> Mark 5:21 When Jesus had again crossed over by boat to the other side of the lake, a large **crowd** gathered around him while he was by the lake. 22Then one of the **synagogue** leaders, named Jairus, came, and when he saw Jesus, he fell at his feet.

> After he put them all out, he took the child’s father and mother and the disciples who were with him, and went in where the child was. 41He took her by the hand and said to her, “Talitha koum!” (which means “Little girl, I say to you, get up!”). 42Immediately the girl stood up and began to walk around (she was twelve years old). At this they were completely astonished. 43He gave strict orders **not to let anyone know about this**, and told them to give her something to eat.

Jesus didn't want the riotous crowd to make him king.

> John 6:15 Jesus, knowing that they intended to come and **make him king by force**, withdrew again to a mountain by himself.

So Jesus didn't mind the non-Jews to talk about his miracles but he minded the over-zealous Jews making him an earthly king.

This is confirmed in the story of the Samaritan woman at the well also.

> John 4:39 Many of the Samaritans from that town believed in him because of the woman’s testimony, “He told me everything I ever did.”

Samaritans and Gentiles talking about Jesus's power was okay but he didn't want the over-zealous Jews to do the same because they misunderstood the purpose of His miracles.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark 5:19 (NASB),

   > *And He did not let him, but He said to him, “Go home to your people and report to them what great things [literally, "everything that"] the Lord has done for you, and how He had mercy on you.”*

   `Why is it that Jesus commanded the demon-possessed man in verse 19 to tell everyone that Jesus delivered him?`

   The answer to your question is: the people of the region beg Jesus to leave. Mark 5:17,

   > *And they began to implore Him to leave their region.*

   So he instructed this man to tell his people and that of the region what had happened. This may have been because:

   - Jesus was asked to leave the region and would not personally give them a witness.
   - And also possibly to counteract any unfavorable reports that might circulate over the loss of the swine.
2. Mark 5:43 (NASB),

   > *And He gave them strict orders that no one should know about this, and He said that something should be given her to eat.*

   - The spreading of the news arouses interest and curiosity in people to the extent that large crowds would prevent Jesus from going freely into the city to preach. Jesus wants people to put faith in him not merely on what they hear from others.
   - Prophecy also says that Jesus does not want sensationalism in the streets.
     Isaiah 42:1-2 (NET Bible),

     > *<sup>1</sup> Here is my servant whom I support, my chosen one in whom I take pleasure. I have placed my Spirit on him;  he will make just decrees for the nations. <sup>2</sup> He will not cry out or shout; he will not publicize himself in the streets.*

Comment: Ruminator, appreciate your edit, thanks